# Как нарисовать треугольник в консоли?

Tags: python

> Звездный треугольник
> Напишите функцию `draw_triangle(fill, base)`, которая принимает два параметра:
> `fill` – символ заполнитель;
> `base` – величина основания равнобедренного треугольника;
> Примечание. Гарантируется, что основание треугольника – нечетное число.
> Тестовые данные

```
Sample Input 1:
*
9
Sample Output 1:
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

А вот   мой код:

```
def draw_triangle(fill, base):
    pass
    fill = input()
    base = int(input()) 
    for i in range(1,base+1):
        print(fill * min(i, base - i + 1))         

draw_triangle(fill, base)
```

Comment: А, всё, я разобрался с форматированием. Вам нужно убрать `pass` и вынести `input`-ы из функции наружу, туда, где её вызов идёт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вводить данные нужно вне функции и `pass` - это пустая заготовка под функцию, она не нужна после того, как вы написали реальный код:

```py
def draw_triangle(fill, base):
    for i in range(1,base+1):
        print(fill * min(i, base - i + 1))         

fill = input()
base = int(input()) 
draw_triangle(fill, base)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)